# How to upload a photo image using Sencha Touch without phonegap

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to upload an image created by the phone using Sencha Touch but without any dependency on PhoneGap?  Basically my app will be accessible via the web, and not installed natively on the device. I want to be able to select an image from the phone storage and then be able to upload it to the service.  I effectively want the same functionality as you would get with the file upload control on a normal desktop browser.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a current solution in its infancy, but it works. I tested it on my Nexus 7 using Chrome. Here is the list of compatibility:

- Android (4.0 up) browser support as regular
- Google Chrome for desktop and mobile
- iOS Safari browser support from version 6.0 (not tested on mobile)

https://github.com/kostysh/File-uploading-component-for-Sencha-Touch

Answer (score 0):

Desktop webbrowser and mobile browser are different in lot many cases. To access file upload option you need to access the OS API which is not possible using javascript only. Phonegap provides us option to connect js with device API. If you can find a way to do this, without using Phonegap, then may be you can fix, or else its not possible.